# When I used color in a cell of a take, then this cell become wider

Tags: tables, color

When I used color in a cell of a take,  then this cell become wider. How to solve it?

[image]

The code is here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\newcommand{\green}[1]{\begingroup\color{green}#1\endgroup}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}

 \begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
      \hline
                      & CCCC &  UUUUU\\
      \hline

      \hline
        AAAAAAAA &   itself &  \green{BBBBBBBBBBBBB}\\ 
      \hline
       AAAAAAAA &   itself &  BBBBBBBB\\ 
     \hline
   \end{tabular}   
 \end{table} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. It contains lots of errors starting with the 1 in newcommand. Beside this use \textcolor{green}{#1} or \leavevmode\color{green}

Comment: strange, the code works for me. Thank you, I think your sugguestion works well.

Comment: Now it will probably work (apart from the fact that I don't have the "default" package. But before the edit it had some error.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

use

```
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
```